# Selenium C# open new incognito browser

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a new incognito browser from an existing chrome driver in selenium C#.

I have tried multiple approaches including action building to send keys which would open the new incognito window (Ctrl+Shfit+N) so I can then use handles to swap between them.
And also have tried some javascript script execution

```
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
  _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

The above works to open a new tab inside the same window but I am unsure of the javascript code (if there is any) which would open a new browser.

```
Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "N").Build().Perform();
```

and
`action.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "N").Build().Perform();`
or sending multiple
`action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).SendKeys("N").Build().Perform()`

The javascript code did what was expected above, however it is not what I am trying to achieve. The send keys code never seemed to do anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Chrome in Incognito needs an entire new instance of the browser itself, therefore a new ChromeDriver instance (you see this happens if you open Incognito in Chrome, it opens a new window and not a new tab). You cannot change a chrome.exe instance to an incognito one halfway or open an Incognito tab.

I suggest you start a new ChromeDriver instance with the correct ChromeOptions:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
```